# TypeError history.js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, transition, history.js

Im trying to implement history api with history.js, im getting into this topic using following tutorial:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lovely-smooth-page-transitions-with-the-history-web-api--cms-26405

I did everything as described, but when Im clicking a link on my site its throwing follow error:

script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

Do you maybe know how I would need to change it so it works? What did I do wrong?

Im using jquery, history.js and the custom.js file from the tutorial which is as follows:

```js
var $wrap = $( "#wrap" );
$wrap.on( "click", ".page-link", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ( window.location === this.href ) {
        return;
    }
    var pageTitle = ( this.title ) ? this.title : this.textContent;
        pageTitle = ( this.getAttribute( "rel" ) === "home" ) ? pageTitle : pageTitle + " â€” Acme";
    History.pushState( null, pageTitle, this.href );
} );

History.Adapter.bind( window, "statechange", function() {
    var state = History.getState();
    $.get( state.url, function( res ) {
        $.each( $( res ), function( index, elem ) {
            if ( $wrap.selector !== "#" + elem.id ) {
                return;
            }
            $wrap.html( $( elem ).html() );
        } );
    } );
} );
```

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help me :(

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for History.js suggests making sure you're loading the code in an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression):

```js
(function(window,undefined){
// Code here
})(window);
```

Source: https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/ (See "Direct Install" section)

Other than that, ensure that your scripts are loading in the order you listed: jQuery, history.js, custom.js. I assume your code is in custom.js and is not on the page (if it is, then that's an entirely different matter).